# Find the equation of the parabola given the tangent to a point and another point.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, self-learning, learning

I have a problem with derivatives, I've been trying to solve but I was not able to do it.

> A parabola is tangent to the line $3x-y+6 = 0$ in the point  $(0,6)$
>   and goes through the point $(1,0)$. Find the equation of the parabola
>   supposing the equation is of the form $y = Ax^2 +Bx +C$ where $A B C$
>   are unknown.

I would like you to help me to solve it. So far I know $(1,0)$ is the vertex of the parabola and that $(0,6)$ is a point of the parabola,thus the directive
is $x=0$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the gradient of the line? What's an equation for the gradient of the parabola?

Comment: Find the slope of the tangent line. Then it follows that $y'(0)$ equals that slope. You also have $y(0) = 6$ and $y(1) = 0$ -> 3 equations, 3 unknowns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the tangent line, we see that the parabola has y'(0)=3 at (0,6). This gives:
$$y'(0)=2A(0)+B=3$$$$B=3$$  From y(0)=6, we get: $$y(0)=A(0)^2+B(0)+C=6$$ $$C=6$$ From y(1)=0, we get: $$y(1)=A(1)^2+3(1)+6=0$$ $$A+9=0$$ $$A=-9$$

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a tangent line, then taking the derivative of your given parabola form will yield

$$y'=2Ax+B$$

and it should be easy to determine the values of $A$ and $B$.  But you are also given a nice point on the parabola, namely $(1,0)$, and this should tell you what $C$ is.