# Find parabola coefficients passing through two known points with given slopes

Tags: systems-of-equations, conic-sections

I would like to find the coefficients of a parabola passing through 2 known points. I also know the slope that the parabola should have at this 2 points. Let me show you a picture of the problem.

[image: problem description]

Known quantities: $(x_{N}, y_{N})$, $(x_{E}, y_{E})$, $\theta_{N}, \theta_{E}$.

Working with the equations I came up with:
$$
\begin{align}
x_{N} &= a \, y_{N}^{2} + b \, y_{N} + c \tag{1} \\
&\Rightarrow \frac{\partial x_{N}}{\partial y_{N}} = 2 a y_{N} + b = \frac{1}{\tan{\theta_{N}}} \tag{2} \\
x_{E} &= a \, y_{E}^{2} + b \, y_{E} + c \tag{3} \\
&\Rightarrow \frac{\partial x_{E}}{\partial y_{E}} = 2 a y_{E} + b = \frac{1}{\tan{\theta_{E}}} \tag{4} \\
\end{align}
$$

I could write a system of three equations, for example:

$$
\left[ \begin{matrix} y_{N}^{2} & y_{N} & 1 \\ 2 y_{N} & 1 & 0 \\ y_{E}^{2} & y_{E} & 1 \end{matrix} \right] \left[ \begin{matrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{matrix} \right] = \left[ \begin{matrix} x_{N} \\ \frac{1}{\tan{\theta_{N}}} \\ x_{E} \end{matrix} \right]
$$

but this will not consider the slope at point E.

If I write this system:

$$
\left[ \begin{matrix} y_{N}^{2} & y_{N} & 1 \\ 2 y_{N} & 1 & 0 \\ 2 y_{E} & 1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right] \left[ \begin{matrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{matrix} \right] = \left[ \begin{matrix} x_{N} \\ \frac{1}{\tan{\theta_{N}}} \\ \frac{1}{\tan{\theta_{E}}} \end{matrix} \right]
$$

it will not consider the separation $x_{E} - x_{D}$.

How can I write a system that satisfy all my constraints?

Comment: Does the parabola have to be in the form $y=f(x)$?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel, no, I used that form because it is the one I am most familiar with. You can use whatever form you'd like, I'm just interested in the results.

Comment: Effectively a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2791927/265466

Comment: Your parabola might not be axis-aligned.

Comment: @amd yes, I think this might be a duplicate... I need to dig into that solution to find if it works for me. Thank you, and yes, I'm quite sure the parabola is not axis-aligned. Thank you! :)